# Drupal 7 Views - Date Filter Cannot See Year

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am trying to create a view with exposed filters for a date field with a start date and required end date.

However, I cannot see the year for the date when I created the filter. I can only see the day and the month. I am using Views 7.x-3.11. I also have both the Date module and Date Views module installed and enabled.

Does anyone know how I can have the year show up in the filter option? I have searched and searched for a solution, but I have not found anything yet.

[image: Filter Options]

Comment: What is your Long date type format set to at `admin/config/regional/date-time`? It looks to me like the format it's showing is whatever is set as your Long date type. If it's set to a format that doesn't show the complete date, you'll run into situations like this in some places.

Comment: My Long data type format is set to "Tuesday, January 26, 2016 - 13:35"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who may be curious, I discovered the issue that was causing the year not to show. @75thTrombone put me on the right track.

After digging through the date popup module, I found that the views filter defaults to the Short date type format, which for my site had been set to `M j` (e.g. Jan 28). Once I added the year back to the Short date type format, the filter worked as expected.

It may be possible to configure which date type is used in the views filter, but I did not see a way to do that. The date popup module is using `variable_get('date_format_short', 'm/d/Y - H:i')`. I will also update the module and see if that allows for a custom configuration.

[image: Update Date Type Configuration]