# Missing Year Filter in Views

Tags: 7, views, datetime

similar issue to 
[Drupal 7 Views - Date Filter Cannot See Year](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188109/drupal-7-views-date-filter-cannot-see-year)

However I verified the format being used is the short date format and in the datepopup.module file, I made sure it was set to m/d/Y but I'm only seeing the month and day.  Under Filter Criteria>Settings>Filter granularity = Year, it displays ok.

Currently running Views, Date, and Calendar modules in this setup.
Last year someone made a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1026084) but it no longer works

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please add an explicit question in the question body. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions.